# Good AS2 Encryption

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I would like to know what Flash AS2 encrypter is the best, I need one that can encrypt it good enough for **most** people to not be able to unencrypt it. It doesn't matter how expensive it is, money isn't an object. I need this for ActionScript **2**, not 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[SWFEncrypt](http://www.amayeta.com/software/swfencrypt/) is pretty good, as it encrypts your SWF, obfuscates the routines in your code, and in general makes it pretty hard to decompile into intelligible code. Obviously it isn't perfect but it will probably take too long and too much effort to get anything intelligible out of a SWF run through it.